# Git bash how to send commit message. M-D, M-M

Tags: git, bash, command

in the past, I used a third party software for git. Now I am trying to use the bash commands. It got really frustrating.
So, when I finish writing the commit message I get many options:

^O: Save

^G: Help

^X: Exit.

So, I do Cntrl+O to save it. Then, it gives me the .git to write the commit message to, and gives me more options.
^G: Help. ^C: Cancel. M-D: DOS Format. M-M: Mac Format. M-A: Add. ... etc.

I don't know which option I should choose, and even if I want to choose DOS Format, I don't know how to actually choose it. I know ^C means Cntrl-C, but what does M-D mean?

I tried to google it for help with no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not `git`. This is `nano`, the text editor.

If you prefer another editor, e.g. `vim`, use `export EDITOR=vim` or less generally `git config --global core.editor vim`

To answer your question, `M-D` refers to the Meta key which on a PC is mapped to Alt. Press `Alt+D`.